# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I am using the Autocomplete box to search the state name purpose. But I am getting the following error raised.

`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete`

What all scripts should I require for this. Please find my code below:

```
        $(function () {
                    $('#txtBState').autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                        if (request.term in cache) {
                            response($.map(cache[request.term].d, function (item)
                            { return { value: item.State, value: item.ChargeID, value: item.ShippingCharge} }))
                        }

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "../Billing/AutocompleteState",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                SearchText: $('#txtBState').val(),
                                SearchText: request.term
                            },
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response(data.slice(0, 5));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: AutoCompleteSelectHandlerState
                });
                function AutoCompleteSelectHandlerState(event, ui) {
                    var selectedObj = ui.item;

                    $('#txtChargeIDs').val(ui.item.ChargeID);
                    $('#txtChargeAmts').val(ui.item.ShippingCharge);
                }
                });
```

**I have used three types of scripts in my View**

*In all the three formats scripts are not supported.*

```
    1)<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/main.css"type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
    2)
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    3)
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that either your data is malformed or there is some other error preventing the autocomplete method from executing. If you're using Firebug or Chrome, you should be able to look at the console log to get a better defined error